# iPad 2 Getting "Unable to Join Network"

Tags: ios, ipad, wifi

I have an iPad 2 that recently stopped being able to connect to Wi-Fi Network. I tried with different routers (one of which is AirPort Extreme), different security settings (including no password), tried resetting to factory both router and iPad, tried resetting network settings and even tried upgrading to iOS 9 all with no luck. Did anyone ever run across this problem?

Comment: What type of encryption is the network using TKIP, AES, or both?

Comment: The router is using AES encryption

Comment: Have you tried changing the password for the network?

Comment: I set the password to a simple one (lower case text and numbers) but no luck

Comment: I completely removed password protection from my Wi-Fi and it still fails to connect. I also tried resetting the iPad and updating to iOS 9 but the problem persisted.